# Warnings in Visual Studio2019 compiling with Boost 1.75

Tags: boost, visual-studio-2019

Just upgraded Visual Studio and did a full recompile of my project. Now get some warnings concerning boost:

```
5>D:\My Libraries\Boost\boost_1_75_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(355,12): warning C4834: discarding return value of function with 'nodiscard' attribute
5>D:\My Libraries\Boost\boost_1_75_0\boost\concept_check.hpp(354): message : while compiling class template member function 'void boost::BinaryFunction<Func,Return,First,Second>::test(boost::false_type)'
5>        with
5>        [
5>            Func=std::less<CString>,
5>            Return=bool,
5>            First=ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>,
5>            Second=ATL::CStringT<wchar_t,StrTraitMFC_DLL<wchar_t,ATL::ChTraitsCRT<wchar_t>>>
5>        ]
```

I see several compiler warnings now that did not appear before.

I should clarify that these warnings only appear in **Release x86** builds (MFC Unicode MD). The x64 Release build is OK.

Comment: Do you compare compilation options beetween the **Release x86** and the **Release x64** at solution level ? you use the same "lib or dll" to link in the **x86** and **x64** configurations ?

Comment: @Landstalker From my end, in my project, nothing has changed between now and yesterday. Except the fact that I upgraded to the latest Visual Studio. Note that I had to recompile my ZipArchive Library to continue building my project too. So I don't know if the Boost libraries need recompiling too. I have not fiddled with any switches or settings in projects at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a known issue, newest version of Visual Studio added `[[nodiscard]]` attribute to `std::equal_to`. The issue has been submitted to boost already https://github.com/boostorg/concept_check/issues/31.

For now, you can fix it by temporarily modify boost/concept_check.hpp file yourself.

```cpp
  BOOST_concept(BinaryFunction,(Func)(Return)(First)(Second))
  {
      BOOST_CONCEPT_USAGE(BinaryFunction) { test(is_void<Return>()); }
   private:
      void test(boost::false_type)
      {
          (void)f(first,second); // add (void) here to silence the warning
          Return r = f(first, second); // require operator()
          (void)r;
      }
```

Or you could add `#pragma warning(disable : 4834)` before including that file, to disable that warning.

Comment: Thank you. That did indeed stop the warnings.